# SubmoduleUpdateCommand getConfigUpdate() returns null

Tags: java, git-submodules, jgit

I have a git repository which contains a submodule and it is pointing to an older commit. I would like to update the submodule to its latest commit using the JGit API

```java
parentGit.getRepository().submoduleUpdate().call();
```

Though the code is executed without any error, I could not see my submodule is pointing to the latest remote commit

```
 SubmoduleWalk::getConfigUpdate
```

always returns `null`.

> Please refer to org.eclipse.jgit.api -> SubmoduleUpdateCommand#call().

```java
SubmoduleWalk walk = SubmoduleWalk.forIndex(parentGit.getRepository());
while(walk.next) {
    walk.getConfigUpdate(); // returns null;
    ...
}
parentGit.getRepository().submoduleUpdate().call(); // does nothing
```

`walk.getConfigUpdate()` should return the value as `ConfigConstants.CONFIG_KEY_MERGE` or `ConfigConstants.CONFIG_KEY_REBASE`, so that upon execution of `parentGit.submoduleUpdateCommand().call()`, the submodules will points to its latest remote HEAD.

Am I missing any repository configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SubmoduleWalk::getConfigUpdate` returns exactly what is set in the repository's configuration key `submodule.<name of module>.update`.

If nothing is set, the method returns `null` and the `SubmoduleUpdateCommand` does checkout the commit referenced in the parent repository's index as a detached HEAD.

Make sure that the index of the parent repository points to the desired submodule commit ID. To choose a different update strategy, you can change the configuration like this:

```java
StoredConfig config = repository.getConfig();
config.setString(CONFIG_SUBMODULE_SECTION, "my-module", CONFIG_KEY_UPDATE, CONFIG_KEY_REBASE); 
config.save();
```

Constants are all declared in `ConfigConstants`.